# Xcode cannot run using the selected device error in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I tried to run my iOS app on iPhone 5 using Xcode, but when I connected it, the iPhone didn't show up in the top-left selection pane. And also when I ran the app from within Xcode, the error: `Xcode cannot run using the selected device error` occurred.

After that, I found that my iPhone was not even found in the organizer; it was there previously. However, after upgrading my OS X to Yosemite beta and iPhone to iOS8 (officially released version of iOS 8), everything doesn't work any more...

The last time I was able to run my apps on iPhone is 5 months ago, so I'm not sure when there's something wrong occurred during the period...

I cleaned and rebuilt the app, and restarted Xcode, but nothing worked.

I also confirmed that I use `Default compiler` in `Build Options`'s compiler settings.

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem. Problem is that your xcode is running on v.5 and there is no option to choose iOS 8 as device system. Try to update your xcode over appstore to v.6

Comment: Upgrading my Xcode (as well as Yosemite) to the latest version resolved the issue! Thanks.